# WPF control similar to outlook new mail alert in the taskbar tray

Tags: wpf, notifications

Is there a WPF control or technique to emulate Outlook's new mail alert in the bottom right of the taskbar tray?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://www.hardcodet.net/projects/wpf-notifyicon) would probably be a good solution.